# Casting ListAdapter to RecyclerView.Adapter fails

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a `RecyclerView.Adapter` class and I want cast it as `ListAdapter`
but it returns an error: "Can not cast".

```
public void setAdapter()
{
    RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(context);
    ListView.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`RecyclerView.Adapter` directly `extends Object`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)

Therefore, you're going to get that error. Besides, I don't think you can use a RecyclerView adapter in a ListView anyways.